How can I prevent my Snowflake Streams going stale?
I use Snowflake Streams for an ETL process that sorts the incoming data out on various parameters and loads it into matching tables.  I have a stream on each of those tables that supports further processes.
Some of these tables can go months without seeing data, and the streams go stale.  I need the streams to stay fresh and ready for data longer than the maximum DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS or MAX_DATA_EXTENSION_TIME_IN_DAYS will allow.
What is a good way to keep these streams fresh?

This is what I'm doing for now.
I have the pipeline re-create the stream at every execution if the stream isn't hydrated.  If the stream is hydrated it is about to be consumed and doesn't need refreshing, and if it isn't hydrated there is no harm in refreshing it.
I use SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA(STREAM_NAME) to check for stream hydration, which will error if you call it on a non-existing or stale stream, so I have to check for that first.  SHOW STREAMS LIKE '%blah%' will tell you if a stream exists and is stale, but it's a keyword so you have to do a SELECT "stale" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))); to get something you can process back.
This is trimmed down from my code and I didn't test it.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXAMPLE(TABLE_NAME VARCHAR, STREAM_NAME VARCHAR, STREAM_SCHEMA VARCHAR, STREAM_DATABASE VARCHAR)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  STRICT
  AS
  $$
    let stream_exists;
    let stream_stale;
    let stream_hydrated;
    const CHECK_STREAM_QUERY_1 = `SHOW STREAMS LIKE '${STREAM_NAME}' IN SCHEMA ${STREAM_DATABASE}.${STREAM_SCHEMA};`;
    const CHECK_STREAM_QUERY_2 = `SELECT "stale" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())));`;
    const CHECK_STREAM_QUERY_3 = `SELECT SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('${STREAM_DATABASE}.${STREAM_SCHEMA}.${STREAM_NAME}');`;
    let check_stream_statement_1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:CHECK_STREAM_QUERY_1});
    let check_stream_statement_2 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:CHECK_STREAM_QUERY_2});
    let check_stream_statement_3 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:CHECK_STREAM_QUERY_3});    

    check_stream_statement_1.execute();
    let check_stream_result = check_stream_statement_2.execute();

    // We recreate any stream that is not hydrated.  SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA errors on a non-existing or stale stream, check that first.
    if (check_stream_result.getRowCount() != 1) {
      stream_exists = false;
      stream_stale = false;
      stream_hydrated = false; 
      } else {
        stream_exists = true;
        check_stream_result.next()
        stream_stale = check_stream_result.getColumnValue(1)
      }
      if (stream_exists && !stream_stale) {
        let check_stream_hydration_result = check_stream_statement_3.execute();
        check_stream_hydration_result.next();
        stream_hydrated = check_stream_hydration_result.getColumnValue(1);
      } else {
        stream_hydrated = false;
      }

    check_table_result.next();
    check_stream_result.next();
    check_func_schema_result.next();
    check_func_result.next();
    check_grant_UDF_list_result.next();

    table_exists = check_table_result.getColumnValue(1);
    func_schema_exists = check_func_schema_result.getColumnValue(1);
    func_exists = check_func_result.getColumnValue(1);
    grant_UDF_list_exists = check_grant_UDF_list_result.getColumnValue(1);

    if (!stream_hydrated) {
      const STREAM_DDL = `CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM ${STREAM_NAME}
                               ON TABLE ${TABLE_NAME}';`;
      try {
        let StreamCreationStatement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:STREAM_DDL});
        let StreamCreationResults = StreamCreationStatement.execute();
        StreamCreationResults.next();

    }
    return true;
  $$;


Executing the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA() only advances the offset when its return value is false. This means that when there is no data at the stream to consume, the calling system function advances offset. When the stream has data, and the return value of SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA() is true, it will not advance offset unless the DML is run on top of the stream.
To demonstrate this behavior, I create a sample script.
//Sample Tables
create or replace table MYTABLE1 (id int);
create or replace table MYTABLE2(id int);

//Stream on Table 1
create or replace stream MYSTREAM on table MYTABLE1;

//validate initial stale_after for stream
show streams like 'MYSTREAM';--2024-05-30 08:09:06.929 -0700

//Ingest data into base table 1
insert into MYTABLE1 values (1);

-- returns true 
select system$stream_has_data('MYSTREAM');

//Validate if stream offset advances when the stream has data and runs system function. You can try rerunning with a few minute's gap.
show streams like 'MYSTREAM'; --2024-05-30 08:09:06.929 -0700 (offset not advanced)

--rerun2 returns true 
select system$stream_has_data('MYSTREAM');

show streams like 'MYSTREAM'; --2024-05-30 08:09:06.929 -0700 (offset not advanced)

-- consume the stream
begin;
insert into MYTABLE2 select id from MYSTREAM;
commit;

-- returns false 
select system$stream_has_data('MYSTREAM');

//Validate if stream offset advances when the stream has NO data and run system function. You may try rerunning with a few minutes gap and notice offset is advancing
show streams like 'MYSTREAM';--2024-05-30 08:09:54.492 -0700(Off set advanced by DML)

-- rerun2 returns false 
select system$stream_has_data('MYSTREAM');

//Validate if stream offset advances when the stream has NO data and run system function. 
show streams like 'MYSTREAM';--2024-05-30 08:11:45.787 -0700(Off set advanced)

Running the "select system$stream_has_data('MYSTREAM');" will not use any warehouse.
In your existing process, you can include the logic in your process to decide to run the DML when the system function retuns true.
